# how to prevent displaying spaces in html code

Tags: html, input, spaces

Let's say we have same 2 input tags with the following difference in html code:

**Example 1**

`<input type="text" id="v1" value="value 1"><input type="text" id="v2" value="value 2">`

**Example 2**

`<input type="text" id="v1" value="value 1">`

`<input type="text" id="v2" value="value 2">`

This two examples produce different output, at least on my PC and my browser which is Chrome [*version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)*]. There is some kind of space between this two inputs! It seems as if browser converts new line to space. But even that is not true because if you make more than one new line between inputs in source that space will still be just one space!

Does anyone know why is that so ???

If so please state what browser (and version) you're using. Oh, yes, [john_h](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5415721/john-h) was kind to make [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zale/dzxvzfhc/2/) code on fiddle

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the white-space between the two inputs is being rendered. Any white-space (line breaks, tabs, spaces) between the inputs will be rendered as a single space by the browser. To fix this, you can set the font-size to 0 on a parent element.

For e.g:

```
<div class="block">

<input type="text" id="v1" value="value 1"><input type="text" id="v2"value="value 2">
<input type="text" id="v1" value="value 1">

<input type="text" id="v2" value="value 2">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .block {
 font-size: 0;
 }
```

This will show no spaces between any inputs u add into the parent element as font-size is set to zero. Hope I was able to clarify your doubts. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Sazz, thank you for clearing that out for me. I have updated fiddle code to https://jsfiddle.net/zale/dzxvzfhc/4/ to reflect your comment...

Comment: Here is a much simpler way to do it rather than using so many divs and css. Check it out. https://jsfiddle.net/dzxvzfhc/5/.

Comment: Right so, neat... ;)

Answer (score 2):

These should produce the same look in a browser, if you have a link to a fiddle, you can send that over or you can take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/john_h/0mz8afyd/1/

One thing you may be experiencing is not having the tags closed.  For example, this:

```
< input type="text" id="v1" value="value 1" >

< input type="text" id="v2" value="value 2" >
```

is different than this:

```
<input type="text" id="v1" value="value 1" />

<input type="text" id="v2" value="value 2" />
```

and also not including spaces between the "<" and "input".

If you want these on two *different* lines, simply add a `<br/>` after your first input.

```
<input type="text" id="v1" value="value 1" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="v2" value="value 2" />
```

Comment: Take a look at how the line difference affects the look: https://jsfiddle.net/john_h/dzxvzfhc/1/  Not having any space between the two input tags creates it right next to each other.  This may be browser related, but if you WANT the space, simply put the input elements on separate lines.  If you DON'T want the space, put them on the same line.  It's a little hackish but it worked.

Comment: No, I don't want that space. I'm trying to get rid of it because it affect the way how I write my code and that is stupid, right? But believe it or not there's a difference at the fiddle link you posted. I'm using Chrome (version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)). What browser are you using? Is there a way to attach some image here?

Comment: I am also using Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

I believe when browser rendering your website, it don't consider the /r/n (which causes a new line in file 1) as new line, instead, it render the /r/n as a white-space (and you use `<br />` to process a new line).

Additional, you use `&nbsp;` to represent a space if you want to make more than one space.

Comment: It seems that code which displays my question made it a bit funny since file 1 and file 2 are actually same. However you guessed right it is all about converting /r/n to space characters when rendered. What I wanted to ask was how to prevent browser from converting /r/n to space. So this question is still unanswered.

Comment: @sasho It is hard to prevent this behavior, although you could try `<input /><\r\n input />` or wrap it inside table cell